# Gridview : How to fill entire space with text view

Tags: android, layout, gridview

I am creating a calendar using `GridView` (6 row * 8 column). Each of the cells inside this matrix (6*8) is a `TextView` (which I create dynamically in my program).

The issue I am facing is, the 6*8 matrix is not filling the entire space available for GridView

I would like to to have the 6*8 matrix take the entire space in `GridView` rather than leaving some blank space b/w the matrix and the next `TextView`. Can some one help me on this.

Given below is the xml layout of the `Gridview`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_weight="1" >

    <GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:numColumns="8"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="1"
            />


    <TextView  
            android:id="@+id/id_worked"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Result 1 ->"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Grid View]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the

```
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
```

from the GridView element. That shoudld reduce the spacing.

Edit: Using LinearLayout you can do this.

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"
android:weightSum="6">
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1">items here</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, I believe you have misunderstood the question. I am not bothered about space b/w each cells in the gridview. I just want no space b/w the gridview & the textView(The textview with id '@+id/id_worked' in layout file). Sorry, I could not attach a snapshot as I still do not have permission to add JPEG in the stack overflow

Comment: Just set the gridview height to wrap_content and textview's layout_weight to 1.Remove the gridview's weight.

Comment: Hi, that is not helping me either. Now I have permission to add JPEG, I have added the Snapshot. Kindly take a look into that. I would not want the Text view(Shown in snapshot as 'Result 1 ->') have a weight of 1. All I want is that 6 rows in Gridview expand to fill the blank space. Hope there is a solution for that. Between I am also wondering if GridView is the right candidate for calendar type application(which has predefined set of rows rather that unknown no of rows). Any suggestions?

Comment: You can keep it simple. Since the number of rows and columns are not going to change you can simply create the layout using LinearLayouts.